# Need to use substring function for all cases?

Tags: c#, regex, c#-3.0

My customer number is `CUS/ABC/15`

for this i have used `substring` like

`string newNo = "CUSTNO"+custobj.CustomerNumber.Substring(custobj.CustomerNumber.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, 2);`

output `CUSTNO15`

But I want to use substring as default method.
for example

if my customer number is `CUST/AB/62`

now to take out `62`
i need to modify substring as below

`CUSTNO"+custobj.CustomerNumber.Substring(custobj.CustomerNumber.LastIndexOf("/"));`

How can I make it default irrespective of `customer number` ?

Comment: what's wrong with your last one for all cases (except that it should be `LastIndexOf("/") + 1`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Split` method.

```
var num = text.Split('/')[2];
```

<sup>If you're asking for something else please provide more info</sup>

Comment: @ashish No, It means split the string with `/` so you get an array of strings `string[] {"CUS", "ABC", "15"}` Then we take the third position (second index). If your input is `CUS/ABC/1588` you'll get `1588`.

Comment: even `Split('/').Last()` is also working same is it ?